# Watch Window in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to specify what members of an object to see in Watch Window without expanding the tree with all the properties. For example:

p = new Point(10 ,10) will display on the Value column in Watch : **{X = 10 Y = 10}**.

For my own classes it always displays : **{MyNamespace.MyClass} or {MyNamespace.MyStruct}**.

Could I change this in order to display : **{ MyStringProperty = "" MyIntProperty = 0 ... }** ?

Comment: If you implement ToString() method, its result will be displayed instead of class/struct name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Using DebuggerDisplay Attribute](http://www.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx)

**If you have marked class by an attribute:**

```
[DebuggerDisplay("x = {X} y = {Y}")]
public class MyClass
{
   public int X { get; private set; }
   public int Y { get; private set; }
}
```

**Output appearing in the Value column of Watch window will be like following:**

```
x = 5 y = 18
```