# Something like DebuggerDisplay for Python?

Tags: python, visual-studio

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776988/watch-window-in-visual-studio), is there any way to get the same functionality of `DebuggerDisplay` attribute for Python? This is my intended code to write:

```
from collections import namedtuple
[DebuggerDisplay("{val}, {dir}")]
Value = namedtuple('Value', ('val', 'dir'))
```

I know `DebuggerDisplay` is a .NET thing. I was just hoping that there was something similar for Python in VS

Comment: It'd help if you gave us some idea what that is supposed to do...

Comment: I'm creating a `namedTuple` called "Value" and I want to change how it is displayed in the VS debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried use [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows%20)?
It has debugger similar to Visual Studio

Comment: I haven't. I'm not opposed to switching; I'm just curious if this can be solved in VS.

Comment: According to Microsoft [link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/python-vs.aspx), Python for vs is an extension and does not have native support.